# May relative adverbs possess consequential nominal descriptors?

Tags: grammar

May relative adverbs possess nominal consequents?

e.g.

wherefrom = "from which"

and

"the proclamation, from which announcement were ascertained the new regulations..."

is a valid formation, thus...

"the proclamation, wherefrom announcement were ascertained the new regulations..."

is *theoretically* correct.

Regardless, this seems to be an odd construction; I have not seen it employed.
Is this valid?

Thank you!

Comment: "wherefrom" is not commonly used in general.

Comment: Wherefore do you risk confusion with whence?  Do you have other examples or just this one specific case seeking something uncommon?

Comment: Whence should have an identical application to wherefrom in the provided sentence. Here is another quotation, from *The Chemist ; Or, Reporter of Chemical Discoveries and Improvements, 1840*: "... under the influence of the sun **with which action** I am at this time occupied I have been led to continue ... ", where *"with which"* may be rewritten as **wherewith**.

Comment: @Mesothorium Initial point: "wherefrom" ("from which") is not an adverb but a compound preposition. It's grammatically correct, though archaic -- possibly to the point where it could be argued that it's not actually grammatical at all.

Comment: 'Wherefrom' could replace  'from which' [archaically] but only when 'which' is not used as a determiner. Thus 'the town from which I came', YES. But 'Elbonia, from which country Dogbert has just returned' NO.

Comment: "wherefrom" <> "from which"  ; "wherefrom" = "whence"

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't correct. The word *which* can be used before a noun because it can act as a determiner in a noun phrase, just like *a* or *the.* Compare these sentences:

1. *Fact proved important later on.
2. **The** fact proved important later on.
3. **That** fact proved important later on.
4. We learned that he was an informant, **which** fact proved important later on.

(1) is incorrect because *fact* needs a determiner. (2)-(4) are all correct because *the, that,* and *which* can all act as determiners. Note that *which* is a dependent of the noun *fact,* not the other way around.

*Wherefrom,* however, cannot act as a determiner, so your example "wherefrom announcement were ascertained the new regulations" would be incorrect.